# Anaconda on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, anaconda

I'm new to Mac, and I recently installed Anaconda on my laptop.  When I installed Anaconda on my Windows laptop, my previous version on Python remained the default version.  However, when I install Anaconda on my Mac. It seems to have erased my previous version.  Or at least when I click on the old version it says "Classic Environment no longer supported".  Additionally, when invoking python from the terminal, it uses the version downloaded with Anaconda.

Now, there are quite a few python modules/packages that Anaconda doesn't support.  So, I'd like to set the default version of python to the original version that came with the Mac.  How would I go about accomplishing that?

Comment: Does this command in the terminal produce anything? `ls /usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: Alright. Try this: `sudo find / -iname python`. When done, post the output to your post. This searches your entire drive for any file named `python`.

Comment: Quite a few things popped up, but here are a few that I believe are important for troubleshooting   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.3/Python
/usr/bin/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Python
/Users/c/anaconda/pkgs/python-2.7.6-1/bin/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python

Comment: Weird that usr/bin/python showed up, but ls /usr/bin/python still says no such file/directory

Comment: Last two things to try: run the `/usr/bin/python` as root: `sudo /usr/bin/python` and, determine what type of file is `/usr/bin/python`: `sudo ls /usr/bin/python`

Comment: su /urs/bin/python   Results in "sorry"  sudo /usr/bin/python launches python

Comment: sudo ls /usr/bin/python doesn't do anything

Comment: That's particularly interesting. It seems that your system python (version 2.7) was overwritten or something to that effect. I would suggest reinstalling it, but as I haven't encountered anything like that before, doing so may wreck your anaconda install (which is unlikely). Hopefully someone else can chime in on that (but, it really seems like that's becoming your most viable option now, unfortunately). Sorry I couldn't be of more help! :(

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm really just starting to get things set up. So, this isn't too pressing.  I might try to uninstall Anaconda, see if that does anything and then reinstall Python.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable approach. Good luck! :)

Comment: So, I'm thinking what happened here is when I installed Anaconda it modified the Python path.  So, I believe I just needed to change the path back to the original version.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but since you ran a search on your system, and the system version wasn't found, I conjectured that something else happened: hence my suggestion to reinstall python (yet to be seconded by others more knowledgeable about anaconda than me).

Answer (score 7):

The installer added a line like

```
# added by Anaconda 1.9.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/you/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

to your `.profile`. That is what makes the Anaconda Python the default in the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

one way is to comment out the line in your file ~./profile 
like this:

```
# added by Anaconda 2.0.0 installer
# export PATH="/Users/username/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
alias pythonA='/Users/username/anaconda/bin/python'
alias conda='/Users/username/anaconda/bin/conda'
alias spyder='/Users/username/anaconda/bin/spyder'
alias pynote='/Users/username/anaconda/bin/ipython_mac.command ; exit;'
```

After that you need to update your path by running from your terminal:

```
source ~/.profile
```

With this you can call your Anaconda python as `pythonA` or install packages using `conda install package` without issues.

Comment: A similar thing can be done for a ``miniconda`` install, e.g. ``alias pyconda='/Users/USERNAME/miniconda3/bin/python'``. Note that a space either side of the equality sign could result in an error ``-bash: alias: =: not found``. I preferred to use the ``pyconda`` name rather than ``pythonA`` since I have miniconda. Naturally one needs to check the proper path first, e.g. ``find / -iname python``